# Nested volley request with Singleton class returns null

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am getting a error in my code. The outer request returns a data but the inner loop returns null.

What I am doing here is: I am requesting some data and again using the id that I get from the first request, i use it to send another request. Although I am receiving the first response, I am getting ERRORNull message in the second nested request.

I am sure that the url is correct. I have not been able to find the solution to this problem.

```
private ArrayList<Item> fetchApiData(){

    String url="http://www.gadgetsinnepal.com.np/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/";

    JsonArrayRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


                    try {

                        // Parsing json array response
                        // loop through each json object

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject item = (JSONObject) response
                                    .get(i);
                            String id = item.getString("id");
                            String date = item.getString("date");
                            JSONObject titleobj = item
                                    .getJSONObject("title");
                            String title= titleobj.getString("rendered");
                            String featuredMedia= item.getString("featured_media");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID :" + id +" Date: "+ date+ " Title "+ title + featuredMedia,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                                    "http://www.gadgetsinnepal.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/"+featuredMedia, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject nested_response) {

                                    try {
                                        // Parsing json object response
                                        // response will be a json object
                                        JSONObject guilld = nested_response.getJSONObject("guid");
                                        String featured_img_url = guilld.getString("rendered");
                                        String nestid=nested_response.getString("id");
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),nested_response.toString()+"IMAGE" + nestid,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "ERROR"+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                            });

                            MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);


                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);


}
```

Comment: Are you aware that you are calling the getInstance of the Singleton with this and a getApplicationContext in this function? They are not the same.

Comment: Sorry didn't know that. What should I write instead of 'getApplicationContext'?

Comment: You could make it both into getApplicationContext.

Comment: I did. And I am still getting the ERRORnull toast message.

Comment: OK, the only ErrorNull message as you describe it seems to come from the onErrorResponse(Volley error). In the future when you make error logs, consider adding a unique string piece to identify in which error log it goes exactly. Thinking logically the VolleyError error object is null. Perhaps it wasn't created properly. Try debugging that for a bit.

Comment: E/Volley: [215] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 503 for http://www.gadgetsinnepal.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/7763
D/Volley: [213] . I got this message in the error log. What do you think it means?

Comment: Responsecode 503 means " Service Unavailable". It means the service is unavailable for your device. It can have tons of reasons and none of them because of something inside your code. You can look them up here: https://www.lifewire.com/503-service-unavailable-explained-2622940

Comment: I fixed the problem. I increased the timeout of the request and that did the job. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: No problem :) I will construct an answer so other viewers will see it is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by carefully examining where the error log was giving.
Having unique logs in your methods will make finding the place where the problem occurs easier to find.

In this case we found that something was happening in:

```
@Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "ERROR"+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Further investigation showed we got a response code 503 message there.
Reasons for this to happen: [lifewire.com/503-service-unavailable-explained-2622940](http://lifewire.com/503-service-unavailable-explained-2622940)

Increasing the time out of the request seems to prevent this from occurring again.